# akka-http: How can I consume/hide an extracted value?

Tags: akka-http, spray-routing

I am trying to write a directive that rejects non-ajax requests. The code below doesn't work obviously:

```scala
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpHeader
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive0
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.HeaderDirectives
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives

trait AjaxDirectives extends BasicDirectives with HeaderDirectives with RouteDirectives {
  private val valid = "XMLHttpRequest"

  def ajax(): Directive0 = {
    headerValueByName("X-Requested-With") { header ⇒
      if (header == valid) {
        pass
      } else {
        reject
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(2 problems here: `pass` is `Directive0` & `headerValueByName` is `Directive1`, and `headerValueByName` is `Directive1` & `ajax` is `Directive0`. So it does not compile)

My question is: **can I somehow have a locally scoped extract?** As in, `header` doesn't escape `ajax`.

---

I know I can access the request to pull the header out, without using `headerValue*`, so please don't answer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading `SecurityDirectives.authorizeAsync` gave me the answer:

```scala
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpHeader
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive0
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.HeaderDirectives
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives

trait AjaxDirectives extends BasicDirectives with HeaderDirectives with RouteDirectives {
  private val headerName = "X-Requested-With"
  private val valid = "XMLHttpRequest"

  def ajax(): Directive0 = {
    headerValueByName(headerName).flatMap { header ⇒
      if (header == valid) {
        pass
      } else {
        reject
      }
    }
  }
}
```